# im having problem when retrieving a blob from a database using java the result i get is a square

Tags: java, mysql, blob, resultset

This is the code I use:

```
package blobdatabase;  

import java.nio.charset.Charset; 
import java.sql.*;  

/**  
 *  
 * @author Edson Lagamayo  
 */  
public class Main {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String returnValue = "";  
        try {  

              Connection con = null;  

            System.out.println("character set : " + Charset.defaultCharset());  

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.90.52/productiondb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8", "root", "root");  

            Statement st;  
            st = con.createStatement();  

            ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("SELECT   imgfilename,field7,field8,field9,field10,field11,field12,field13,field14,field15,field16,field17,field18,field19,field20,field21,field22,field23,remarks1,remarks2,remarks3,remarks4,remarks5,remarks6,remarks7,remarks8,remarks9,remarks10,remarks11,remarks12   FROM (SELECT MAX(stampid) stampid,orderid,projid,jobid,taskcode FROM tstasks t WHERE t.jobid=187 AND taskcode=1 GROUP BY t.orderid)t LEFT JOIN orderdetail od ON od.seqid=t.stampid AND od.orderid=t.orderid RIGHT JOIN imageinfo ii ON ii.orderid=od.orderid AND ii.projid=t.projid WHERE t.jobid=187;");  
            while (resultSet.next()) {  
                Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("remarks7");  
                returnValue = blob != null ? new String(blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length())) : "";  
                System.out.println("returnValue : " + returnValue);  
            }  

          } catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }  
}
```

the output i'm having is :

```
returnValue : ��4546345435435sdfaf4324324  
returnValue : �  
returnValue : sdafghbgjbgjnbhgnjbggbvrfsdfsdcvewr54trtgdfg���fdsjdgfdgdgfdfgdgsdafghbgjbgjnbhgnjbggbvrfsdfsdcvewr54trtgdfg���f
```

�� is sometimes a square the value for this would be ÑÑ
can anyone help me with this?  please help me solve my problem
:)

Comment: We could do that if we knew your problem. For example, what did you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Why are you calling `blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length())` with `startpos = 1`?? Try 0 and look if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Generally if character data is to be stored/retrieved, people use CLOB, not BLOB.

Comment: Further: The ? chars just mean that the font you use to print the text out is not supporting the binary value of the character. If you have unicode chars at the locations with the ? you may want to write the text to a file which you can open with an editor supporting the characters you want to see (for testing).

Comment: @ZeissS: not exactly: `?` would indicate a character not representable by the output console, an empty square (or a square containing some hex digits) usually indicates a glyph unsupported by the current font and a `�` indicates that the `byte` values are not valid in the encoding used to decode them.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Thanks for info. Haven't known that.

Comment: i would like to have an output like Ñ

Answer (score 0):

```
useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

...only tells the driver to blindly assume it's UTF-8. It does NOT set the character encoding of the connection. You should set the default charset to UTF-8 in mysql config, or run the following query right after connection:

```
SET names utf8
```

Comment: "Ñ LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE  "this is the letter i want for output. i have paste the whole code for my program then i don't know what to do.. : when i want to get the value Ñ from the database i only get the result ?? or the square like the output ABOVE ^ :)

Comment: @Tsuna Sawada Does this happen after running `SET names utf8`? What kind of console are you using for `System.out`? (If it is a terminal window it is possible that the terminal itself is not UTF-8 capable).

Comment: @vbence the console is capable of printing that letter... because i try System.out.println("Ñ"); and it prints Ñ in the console.  and also i dont know how to execute "SET names utf8" in java.. how can i execute it before the connection?

Comment: @Tsuna Sawada I did not right *before* I wrote "right after". This is an SQL query. You can run it with `executeQuery()` or in numerous other ways.

Comment: @vbence.. i have search some codes then i found this but i dont know what is the meaning of this..   Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("Remarks1");
    String text = blob != null ? new String(blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()), "UTF-8") : "";
    System.out.println("text1 : "+text); but still i gets the wrong data ..

Comment: @Tsuna Sawada Please edit your example code in the original question to show how you inserted the `SET names utf8`.